# Angular When to unsubscribe()?

Tags: angular

So, I'm a little unclear on the unsubscribe() method.

It seems like the proper place to do it is in the ngOnDestroy() life cycle method? So I did that in the code below. BUT, the deleteFile() method won't execute now?

I read the below in another thread: (is this correct?)

> "You shouldn't manually unsubscribe, 90% of the time. In this specific
>   case, you're using a service to fetch data. If this service uses an
>   http call, and thus the HttpClient, the observable is already closed
>   once the call is finished and closed observables are already
>   unsubscribed."

So do I need to unsubscribe here or not? Thanks

```
...
export class UploadComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
 private subscriptions: Subscription;
...

ngOnDestroy() {
 this.subscriptions.unsubscribe();
}

deleteFile(id: any) {
 if (window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this file?")) {

  const sub = this.fileCabinetService.deleteFile(id)
    .subscribe(
      res => {

        ...
      },
      error => {

        ...
      }
    );

  this.subscriptions.add(sub);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have misunderstood how `Subscription` and `add` work.

When you `subscribe` to something, you get a `Subscription` object, to which you can call `unsubscribe()`. This is fine. However, you haven't assigned the value correctly. You assigned the `Subscription` to `const sub`, which you then pass in as the `completion` block to `add`.

Consider `Subscription.add` like a `finally` block of a `try/catch`. No matter what the result of the `Subscription`, when it is `complete`, the block passed to `add` will execute. Use this for any cleanup tasks.

```js
subscriptions: Subscriptions[] = [];

ngOnDestroy() {
   subscriptions.forEach((sub) => sub.unsubscribe());
}

deleteFile(id: any) {
   const sub = this.fileCabinetService.deleteFile(id).subscribe(...);
   this.subscriptions.push(sub);
   sub.add(() => this.subscriptions.remove(sub));
}
```

---

To answer your question about when to `unsubscribe`, it really depends on what `deleteFile` does. If the `deleteFile` method internally signals with a value (or a set of values) and then is completed, the subscription is terminated automatically. If it is not completed and left dangling, then your subscription will persist.

Consider the scenario of:

```js
WallClock.subscribe((time) => console.log(time));
```

This `Subscription` will never be terminated because time (presumably) will continue indefinitely. Instead, you will want to manually control when this is terminated. You can do this in a few ways:

```js
/* Get the current time, but don't bother listening to updates. */
WallClock.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((time) => console.log(time));

/* Continually update with the current time as long as the component is on screen
   — Requires setting `this.staySubscribed = false` when you're leaving */
WallClock.pipe(takeWhile(() => this.staySubscribed)).subscribe((time) => console.log(time));

/* Continually update until you remember to unsubscribe
   — Requires remembering to unsubscribe and can get verbose with multiple subscriptions
   - Call `this.subscription.unsubscribe()` later */
this.subscription = WallClock.subscribe((time) => console.log(time));
```

If your `deleteFile` operates like this and continually reports values without a definite completion condition, you should make sure to terminate the subscription in some way. It is likely the case (based on the name of the function) that this is a self-terminating `Subscription` that will not require anything on your part. If you want to be really safe, the `pipe(take(1))` will ensure it for you.

Answer (score 1):

With regard to unsubscribe, you should take a look at the `takeUntil` pattern outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41177163/3718246). It is the preferred way to unsubscribe and avoid memory leaks. You could refactor your code to something like this:

```js
...
export class UploadComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
   private ngUnsubscribe = new Subject();
...

ngOnDestroy() {
   this.ngUnsubscribe.next();
   this.ngUnsubscribe.complete();
}

deleteFile(id: any) {
   if (window.confirm("Are you sure you want to delete this file?")) {

   this.fileCabinetService.deleteFile(id)
     .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
     .subscribe(
       res => {
        ...
      },
      error => {
        ...
      }
    );
 }
}
```

**That having been said**, if you are subscribing to an `@angular/common/http` observable, you don't need to unsubscribe because the `http` service calls `complete()` when data is returned. Take a look at [this implementation in the xhr back-end](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/http/src/backends/xhr_backend.ts#L92) for details:

```js
if (response.ok) {
  responseObserver.next(response);
  // TODO(gdi2290): defer complete if array buffer until done
  responseObserver.complete();
  return;
}
```

So, for `@angular/common/http` requests, don't worry about it. For most others, follow the `takeUntil` pattern.

Comment: Assuming the `FileCabinetService` directly returns the `Observable` from an `HTTP` service in the method `deleteFile(id)` that `observable object` is completed and requires no `unsubscribe` call?

Comment: @Itanex correct. The framework will `complete` your observable for you so you don't have to unsubscribe. That said, I usually want to cancel my HTTP call if a user navigates to a new page anyway. So, I usually use the `takeUntil` pattern for that reason but I it depends on the page/route being called.

Comment: My use of RXJS is not as avarice as most, I have rolled it into my development skills only recently. I have seen `takeUntil` and understand its function. Though up until recently, when I needed a subscription to unsubscribe I would usually do the following `const sub = myFunction().subscribe(() => sub.unsubscribe())`. This is obviously a highlight and not the entire code. I use this pattern when doing things like sending a delete/update that is out of band to the angular lifecycle hooks. or the ASYNC pipe. Which as it turns out, is very few and far between